# GPG Encrypt Fails in IIS .net App but works in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, encryption, iis-7, gnupg

Workstation: Win7 Pro

Server: Win 2008

VB.net - using the `System.Diagnostics.Process` tools

Gpg4win 2.2.5 in stalled on both computers.

The Key Pair was generated on Win 7 and backed up to the server.

A public key was provided by the recipient.

Both keys were moved to a file share

Both gpg installations were cleared of all keys.

The Backup of the key pair was imported as well as the Public key of the recipient.

Both keys were trusted. This was all done in DOS command window.

```
gpg --allow-secret-key-import --import "//fileshare/KeyBackup.gpg"
```

(results indicate Secret key is available)

```
gpg --allow-secret-key-import --import "//fileshare/PUBLIC.asc"
```

`gpg --edit-key pairkey@mycompany.com` (trusted "ultimately")

`gpg --edit-key publicKeys@their.com` (trusted "ultimately")

**In visual studio, on my work station, a vb.net app successfully encrypts and signs a file.**

**Move the app to the server and run under IIS, encryption fails with message, "No Secret Key".** To make it more fun, encryption DOES work on the server if you use manual DOS commands.

The file to be encrypted is on a share and both applications reference it.

That I can tell both Gpg4win installations are identical and have the very same keys. Both keys were imported from the same location in the same manner.

I await the opinions of the superior minds of Stackoverflow.

Thanks

Comment: GnuPG uses per-system-user key rings. Have you really imported the keys from the very same system user as the service is running under?

Comment: The keys were created under my credentials on my workstation. The webapp is not impersonating, so it utilizes system resources such as shares as the server. Hmmm.. I'll look into that. Thanks

Comment: Then this will be the issue. Dumping the output of `gpg --version` might reveal some information on your home directory, or simply import the keys from within your application. It _must be_ running in some user's context, but you'll have to find out which one.

Comment: Well, I stumbled acorss the answer, or at least a fix. I can offer no cogent explanation about why it works, but it does.

Comment: While searching for an answer based on your suggestion I ran across a post that showed how to specify the location of the public, trust, and secret key files, which are normally located in the AppData\Local\Temp folder

I figured that GPG was looking for the keys in that folder, except for the Application Pool identity, which of course doesn't have one. So, using those commands, I was able to encrypt a file via a webapp running under IIS with an different identity than myself. 

I'll post the exact command tomorrow when I get to work.

Comment: @Dthompson What was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I tried setting the GNUPGHOME environmental variable to a specific location, my ASP.NET application running from IIS didn't seem to honor it and couldn't find my keys.

**Eventually I discovered it kept trying to find the key files from c:\gnupg on the iis server (irrespective of GNUPGHOME). I copied all the keyring files to that location, and it finally worked.**